# XML-JSON Converter Rules

Tags: xml, json, serialization, json-simple

I'm using net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer to convert XML documents to JSON. I'm getting two different results for almost two similar XML documents. My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
    String t1="<A><B>aa</B><C><D>Martin Ritt</D> </C></A>";
    String t2="<A><B>aa</B><C><D>Martin Ritt</D></C></A>";
    System.out.println(new XMLSerializer().read(t1).toString());
    System.out.println(new XMLSerializer().read(t2).toString());
}
```

The first string t1 is converted to:

```
{"B":"aa","C":["Martin Ritt"]}
```

while t2 is converted to:

```
{"B":"aa","C":{"D":"Martin Ritt"}}
```

That means, in the first case, C is considered an array while in the second case, it is considered an object. The difference between the two XMLs is the space after the closing of the D element. That is, after `</D>`.

Any idea what is going on here? what is the rule? I'm more interested in how to make it recognize arrays consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are:

- Root nodes are discarded, in this case `<A>`
- Element nodes with text node children =>

  ```
  {"Element":"text node"}
  ```
- Element nodes with element children =>

  ```
  {"Element":{"Element":"text node"} } //t1
  ```
- Element nodes with mixed children (element + white space) =>

  ```
  {"Element":["text node"]} //t2
  ```

**References**

- [XSLTJSON: Transforming XML to JSON using XSLT](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/)
- [Convert XML to JSON using XSLT](https://www.bjelic.net/2012/08/01/coding/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt/)
- [Mapping Mixed Content](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/779#mixed)
- [Identify Node Type](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nodetest.html#d7657e255)